# Warning: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, warnings

I'm getting this warning with my JS React Bootstrap code.

> Warning: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

My code is working exactly as intended, so the warning isn't causing any functionality issues, but still, I'd like to resolve it.

Here's the code that's causing the warning:

```html
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>Availability</Form.Label>
      <div onChange={ (e) => this.handleInput(e, "listing")}>
        <Form.Check checked={(this.state.listing.availability === "募集中")} type="radio" value="募集中" name="availability" label="募集中"/>
        <Form.Check checked={(this.state.listing.availability === "契約済")} type="radio" value="契約済" name="availability" label="契約済"/>
      </div>
    </Form.Group>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1.1}}>
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>Property Type</Form.Label>
      <div onChange={ (e) => this.handleInput(e, "property")}>
        <Form.Check checked={(this.state.property.property_type === "一戸建て")} type="radio" value="一戸建て" name="property_type" label="一戸建て"/>
        <Form.Check checked={(this.state.property.property_type === "アパート")} type="radio" value="アパート" name="property_type" label="アパート"/>
      </div>
    </Form.Group>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 0.9}}>
    <Form.Group>
      <Form.Label>Interest</Form.Label>
      <div onChange={ (e) => this.handleInput(e, "property")}>
        <Form.Check checked={(this.state.property.interest === "Extremely")} type="radio" value="Extremely" name="interest" label="Extremely"/>
        <Form.Check checked={(this.state.property.interest === "Kinda")} type="radio" value="Kinda" name="interest" label="Kinda"/>
        <Form.Check checked={(this.state.property.interest === "Nah")} type="radio" value="Nah" name="interest" label="Nah"/>
      </div>
    </Form.Group>
  </View>
 </View>
```

I have certain reasons for formatting things this way, but I'm totally open to suggestions. Really, I just want get rid of the warning with changing this code as little as possible.

I saw there were other questions addressing this issue, but I couldn't find a solution that works with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning message seems pretty clear. If you want it to disappear then you should add `readOnly` attribute to the Form.Check components.

```
<Form.Check checked={(this.state.listing.availability === "募集中")} type="radio" value="募集中" name="availability" label="募集中" readOnly/>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty clear. Guess I didn't exactly know what it meant by "set readOnly"

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:
I had the following code that gave me the similar error:

```
  <input
  type="radio"
  className="tabs__radio"
  name="tabs-example"
  id="tab1"
  checked    **solution: just change checked to defaultChecked**
  />
```